# Adding and styling side button with jQM

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

So what I'm trying to do is to add a button on the left side on the screen, which should be round shaped (not necessarily), half visible and good looking. With this button the user will be allowed to open the side menu panel.

Here is the html code of the button:

```
<a id="settingsButton" data-rel="panel" data-role="button" href="#optionsPanel" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-icon-alt ui-icon-nodisc ui-btn-right">Settings</a>
```

And a js sample, which dynamically sets the style:

```
function setSettingsButton(){
    $("#settingsButton").css({
        left:"-15px",
        top:$(window).height() / 2 - 30 + "px",
        position:"fixed"
    });
}
```

The function is called on document ready.

This code styles the button pretty good, but it is too small. When I try to adjust the size using `style="width: 10%; height: 10%;"` the button loses it's round shape and gets pretty ugly.

EDIT:
[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/nySw3/3/) Adding style="width:10%; height:10%;" or any size adjustment causes the button to look square and ugly.

So can you give me tips for styling a good looking and big enough button?

Comment: please share your code on fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please edit your question and put the link to your fiddle in there.

As for the solution: The circle is made with a `border-radius`. This rounds the corners using css. Let's say I have a square with ribs of 10px. To make it a circle, I would need a border-radius of 5px on each corner. If I now change the size of my ribs to 20px, it will not be a circle anymore, but a square with rounded corners. This is what you're doing.

To solve this, you must also change the `border-radius` accordingly. Here's an example:

```
$("#settingsButton").css({
    left:"-30px",
    top:$(window).height() / 2 - 30 + "px",
    position:"fixed",
    'border-radius':'30px',
    height:'60px',
    width:'60px'
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nySw3/4/).

Now, I've never used jQuery Mobile, so I'm not sure whether there is a built-in option to enlarge it, because using this method as you will see will not enlarge the *i*-icon inside it.